# C# - Create and return muti-type generic from unary typed methods (or classes)

Tags: c#, generics, dynamic

Here's the scenario:

Create an instance with multiple generic types like:

```
var obj = myBuilder
            .Combine<TypeA>()
            .And<TypeB>
            .And<TypeC>
            .Create();
```

I want **obj** returned by Create() to be typed over 

`Combined<TypeA, TypeB, TypeC>`

I know I can create generic instance with `MakeGenericType` but how to combine and return generic types on different methods?

I don't want to return object from `Create()` typecast in client code. I feel it's redundant and ugly:

```
var obj = (Combined<TypeA, TypeB, TypeC>) myBuilder
              .Combine<TypeA>()
              .And<TypeB>
              .And<TypeC>
              .Create();
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Currying](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) works for ether type of arguments - type or parameters.

So you can relatively easy create classes that will do what you want for particular type in C#. One possible way is capture types into intermediate classes like:

```
   class Captured<T>
   {
      public Captured<T,U> And<U>() { return new Captured<T,U>();}
   }

   class Captured<T,U>
   {
      public Captured<T,U, V> And<V>() { return new Captured<T,U,V>();}
   }

   class Captured<T,U, V>
   {
      public Combined<T,U, V> Build() { return new Combined<T,U,V>();}
   }
```

Comment: I almost invented it but I'm glad I posted this. I'd never know of currying. Thanks!

Comment: I posted an alternative with static nested classes, accomplishes same goal with less instances.

Answer (score 1):

Although currying works, the code used creates one too many instances in the process as my colleague at work pointed out. The intent is to really get `Combined<T,U,V>` and using several intermediate objects seemed heavy handed. Static classes are an alternative and to my surprise, nested static classes with generics works beautifully and code is quite elegant for this purpose. I'm glad we even have the feature of nested classes in C#. I'm posting sample code for anybody who stumbles on similar problem out there.

```
public static class Combine<T>
{
    public static class With<U>
    {
        public static class And<V>
        {
            public static CombinedType<T, U, V> Create
            {
                get
                {
                    return new CombinedType<T, U, V>();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
class CombinedType<T, U, V> { }

class TypeA { }
class TypeB { }
class TypeB { }

// client call
var type = Combine<TypeA>.With<TypeB>.And<TypeC>.Create;
```

Comment: +1: indeed this is much more compact version and unlike mine does not create any objects unnecessary.